# Error in importing a module in rest_framework, while creating rest API using Django framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework

I created a web application using Djanjo framework, and then when I am trying to create a REST API, after configuring all the relevant files  such as models.py, admin.py, serializers.py, views.py, and settings.py. It shows an error while importinng the model from rest_framework. The traceback is as follows:

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dmandal\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\dmandal\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dmandal\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dmandal\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\dmandal\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\dmandal\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dmandal\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\dmandal\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\dmandal\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\dmandal\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 399, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\dmandal\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\dmandal\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 584, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\dmandal\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\dmandal\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 577, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\dmandal\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\myproject1\myproject1\urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    from webapp import views
  File "C:\myproject1\webapp\views.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . serializers import employeesSerializer
  File "C:\myproject1\webapp\serializers.py", line 2, in <module>
    from rest_framework import employees
ImportError: cannot import name 'employees' from 'rest_framework' (C:\Users\dmandal\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\__init__.py)*
```

The serializer.py is as follows:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework import employees

class employeesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = employees
#        fields = ('firstname','lastname')
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: why are you trying to import employees from  rest_framework

Comment: I created a class employees                                                                                                            class employees(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    emp_id = models.IntegerField()
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname

Answer (score 1):

It's name conflict. Please change the name of your app to something else other then rest_framework.